# how to make an xsl:value-of bold

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

I have the following XSL code:

```
          <td class="info center">
            <div class="infoBoldBlue"><xsl:value-of select="office" /></div>
            <xsl:value-of select="Address/Address1" /><br />
            <xsl:if test="Address/Address2 != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="Address/Address2" />
              <br />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="Address/City" />, <xsl:value-of select="Address/State" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Address/zip" /><br />
            <xsl:value-of select="Address/phone" />
          </td>
```

I am trying to make the `<xsl:value-of select="Address/Address2" />` bold. How can I do that?

I tried adding a `span` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a strong tag around it as follows:

```
<td class="info center">
            <div class="infoBoldBlue"><xsl:value-of select="office" /></div>
            <xsl:value-of select="Address/Address1" /><br />
            <xsl:if test="Address/Address2 != ''">
              <strong>
                <xsl:value-of select="Address/Address2" />
              </strong>
              <br />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="Address/City" />, <xsl:value-of select="Address/State" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Address/zip" /><br />
            <xsl:value-of select="Address/phone" />
</td>
```

Comment: @SiKni8 Really? That works perfectly fine for me every time. Is it just visibly not bold? Could there be a styling override happening else where. Is the <strong> tag rendered out into the html?

Comment: I know it is weird. I don't even see the `<strong>` tag in the html output file...

Comment: @SiKni8 It must be caching it or something, have you tried doing an iis reset?